# Is it possible to stop UglifyJS from injecting "_" as a replacement name?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

Is there a way to configure Uglify with a blacklist of strings that should not be injected during replacement?

For example, Uglify is currently replacing `TypeError` with `_`:

`TypeError("Promise can't be resolved")` => `_("Promise can't be resolved")`.

But, I'm running static post-processing on the Uglified code to extract strings marked with `_`:

`_("Marked by the developer")`.

Uglify's injection of `_` to replace TypeError is generating false positives during the post-process extraction.

I know it is possible to stop function/class name mangling all together, and to prevent mangling for reserved names.

But, is there a way I can tell Uglify to do regular mangling, just that `_` should not be injected during replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried specifying the `reserved` option and passing in `_` to that? I would expect that it wouldn't replace it knowing that is a special name.

Comment: It turns out this works after all, despite not being the documented purpose: "When mangling is enabled but you want to prevent certain names from being mangled, you can declare those names with --mangle reserved" (i.e. prevents _ from getting renamed to something else.)

Comment: But because of https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/blob/9f23185f2bb0d23d5dd2e2334c589e97132a37a8/lib/scope.js#L334-L336, mangle reserved also has the effect of preventing reserved names from being injected in local scopes during replacement (thanks @mihai-parparita for the pointer) -- i.e. prevents anything else from getting renamed to _ (my goal).

Comment: Fun fact in case anyone else hits this - I was using Uglify as part of webpack, and uglifyjs-webpack-plugin2 does not use mangle: {reserved: [...]} as you'd expect from https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2. Instead, the NPM module is at https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/v2.x#mangle so the syntax was mangle: {except: [...]}.